# Error when getting window handle using JNA

Tags: java, jna

I am trying to get the coordinates of the foreground window using the Java Native Access SDK. Already at the beginning I am getting an error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized calling convention: 3
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:477)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:411)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:323)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.GetForegroundWindow(Unknown Source)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:42)
Java Result: 1`

The only code I have in Test.java is this:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;


public class Test {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HWND fgWindow = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
   }
}
```

The code will compile, and I am able to retrieve the User32.INSTANCE, so that's not the problem. The problem will only occur if I try to access the method GetForegroundWindow(). I also tried to fix this by compiling the jar files by extracting the source jars and adding them to my project in the source folder. No compilation errors occur but the error remains. I also tried to use the option of adding the extra interface to the code:

```
public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
  User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
  HWND GetForegroundWindow();  // add this
  int GetWindowTextA(PointerType hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
}
```

However the error remains...

What can I do?

EDIT: I am using this code on a windows 10 system.

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit JVM?  There may be a bug in 64-bit windows properly ignoring requests for `stdcall` calling convention.

Comment: I am using 64 bit JVM (this is returned by executing System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") );) and version 4.2.1 JNA (the most recent version). I tried installing 32 bit JVM but when downloading () I don't get the option to select 32/64 bit.

Comment: nvm: I solved it!!! You were right I need a 32-bit JRE but also a 32-bit SDK (which comes with the 32 bit JRE), using that I solved it! thanks a lot!

Comment: Nonetheless, that should still work under a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: From my experience, this is a regression in JNA 4.2.x. It doesn't happen in JNA 4.1.0.